# bcp フォーマットファイル作成について

Tags: sql-server

作業pcはmac mojave  
dbはazureのsqldatabaseを使用しています

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-2017#macos
の中にある
MacOS でのツールをインストールします。
に従いツールをインストールを行いました
その後に、存在するテーブルtable1のフォーマットファイルを作成する為下記を実行しました

```
bcp test.dbo.table1 format nul -f ./table1.fmt -c -U user -P password -S testsv.database.windows.net -t, -r\n
```

実行した結果、

```
A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options.
```

とエラーになりました
接続情報に問題があるのかと思い

```
sqlcmd -S testsv.database.windows.net -U user -P password -d test
```

としたところ接続することは出来ました

エラー情報からオプションに問題があるようなのですが、解決出来ず
ご指摘いただけないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました

```
bcp dbo.table1 format nul -f table1.fmt -c -U user -P password -S testsrv.database.windows.net -d test -t , -r \n
```

`-d` オプションを使うようでした